# Does draggable/resizable not work with jquery 1.11.1 and jquery-ui 1.10.3?

Tags: jquery, draggable, resizable

The code is simple  -

```
$("#chat_widget_container_iframe").draggable( {containment: "#rtcdemo-background-layer", scroll: false} );
$("#chat_widget_container_iframe").resizable({
 // maxHeight: 250,
 // maxWidth: 350,
  minHeight: 270,
  minWidth: 300
});
```

If I change jquery to 1.7.2, then the code works. But I need 1.11.1 for other things in the page. How can I make it work with 1.11.1?

I get the error " Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function "

Comment: the code looks fine and should work in the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: The error I get is: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function